# Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets with $\#A=\#\mathbb{Z}$ and $\#B=\#\mathbb{Z}$. (a) Prove $\#(A\cup B)=\#\mathbb{Z}$. (b) Is $\#(A\cap B)=\#\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: cardinals

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets with $\#A=\#\mathbb{Z}$ and $\#B=\#\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\#(A\cup B)=\#\mathbb{Z}$.
> 2. Is it necessarily true that $\#(A\cap B)=\#\mathbb{Z}$?

I'm sure that I need to use bijection to prove this, but I don't know the exact way since these are new stuff for me.

Comment: Does your $Z$ mean $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of all integers? Or is $Z$ an arbitrary set? In the latter case, the statement in (a) isn't true...

Comment: It means the set of all integers, I just couldn't paste the letter like this here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$ is a well known fact that countable unions (in this case, finite) of countable sets are countable.

$(2)$ is false; consider $A$ the set of even integers and $B$ the set of odd integers.

Comment: Ohh yeah it makes sense now, thank you a lot